Communication with the public internet is not working in kubernetes set up
I set up a kubernetes cluster with 1 control plane node and 2 worker nodes on hetzner cloud. All the nodes are running ubuntu-24.04 on hetzner and below are the scripts I have used in the setup.
Below is the script that attempts to set up the control plane
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current user
USER="root"

# Remove existing Kubernetes repo if any
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

# Disable swap
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sed -i '/swap/d' /etc/fstab

# Create the kubelet configuration directory if it doesn't exist
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d

# Create the 20-hetzner-cloud.conf file with the necessary configuration
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-hcloud.conf
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=external"
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
overlay
br_netfilter
EOF

sudo modprobe overlay
sudo modprobe br_netfilter

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
EOF

# Apply sysctl params without reboot
sudo sysctl --system

# Install containerd and other required components
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    gpg \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Add Docker’s official GPG key
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

# Set up the Docker stable repository
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list >/dev/null

# Update the package database with Docker packages from the newly added repo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y containerd.io curl socat
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd
sudo containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo sed -i 's/ SystemdCgroup = false/ SystemdCgroup = true/' /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo sed -i '/\[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"\]/,/disable_apparmor/ s/disable_apparmor = .*/disable_apparmor = true/' /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
sudo systemctl enable containerd

sudo mkdir -p -m 755 /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.29/deb/Release.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg

echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.29/deb/ /' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl

systemctl enable --now kubelet

The following script gets executed after the above script is done to finalize the set up of the control plane:
#!/bin/bash

USER="root"
LOAD_BALANCER_IP=$(cat /home/$USER/control_plane_load_balancer_ip.txt)
echo "Load Balancer IP=$LOAD_BALANCER_IP"

if [ -z "$LOAD_BALANCER_IP" ]; then
    echo "Error: Load Balancer IP not found in /home/$USER/control_plane_load_balancer_ip.txt. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if Kubernetes is already initialized by checking the existence of the kubeconfig file
if [ -f /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ]; then
    echo "Kubernetes is already initialized. Skipping kubeadm init..."
else
    echo "Kubernetes is not initialized. Initializing Kubernetes..."

    # Initialize Kubernetes using the load balancer IP
    sudo kubeadm init \
        --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
        --control-plane-endpoint "$LOAD_BALANCER_IP" \
        --cri-socket=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock \
        --upload-certs

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Kubernetes initialized successfully."

        # Set kubeconfig
        mkdir -p ~/.kube
        sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
        sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.kube/config

        # Apply Flannel CNI network configuration
        export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        kubectl apply -f https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/releases/latest/download/kube-flannel.yml

        # Persist KUBECONFIG across sessions
        echo "export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" >>/home/$CURRENT_USER/.bashrc
        source /home/$CURRENT_USER/.bashrc

        echo "Flannel CNI applied and KUBECONFIG set up successfully."

        # Create /run/flannel/subnet.env if it doesn't exist
        if [ ! -f /run/flannel/subnet.env ]; then
            sudo mkdir -p /run/flannel
            {
                echo "FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16"
                echo "FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24"
                echo "FLANNEL_MTU=1450"
                echo "FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true"
            } | sudo tee /run/flannel/subnet.env >/dev/null
            echo "Flannel subnet configuration file created successfully."
        else
            echo "Flannel subnet configuration file already exists. Skipping creation."
        fi

    else
        echo "Error: kubeadm init failed."
        exit 1
    fi
fi

And the control plane initializes successfully all the time. Now, here is the code that sets up the worker nodes:
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current user
USER="root"
SSH_KEY="..."
CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS_FILE="/home/${USER}/control_plane_node_ips.txt"
KUBECONFIG_PATH="/home/${USER}/kubeconfig"

# Remove existing Kubernetes repo if any
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

# Disable swap
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sed -i '/swap/d' /etc/fstab

# Create the kubelet configuration and network directories if they don't exist
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d

# Create the 20-hetzner-cloud.conf file with the necessary configuration
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-hcloud.conf
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=external"
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
overlay
br_netfilter
EOF

sudo modprobe overlay
sudo modprobe br_netfilter

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
EOF

sudo sysctl --system

# Install containerd and other required components
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    gpg \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Add Docker’s official GPG key
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

# Set up the Docker stable repository
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list >/dev/null

# Update the package database with Docker packages from the newly added repo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y containerd.io socat
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd
sudo containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo sed -i 's/ SystemdCgroup = false/ SystemdCgroup = true/' /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo sed -i '/\[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"\]/,/disable_apparmor/ s/disable_apparmor = .*/disable_apparmor = true/' /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
sudo systemctl enable containerd

mkdir -p -m 755 /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.29/deb/Release.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg

echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.29/deb/ /' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl

systemctl enable --now kubelet

CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS=$(cat "$CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS_FILE")
echo "Control Plane Node IPS = $CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS"
IFS=',' read -r -a CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS <<<"$CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS"

if [ ${#CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    SHUFFLED_IPS=($(shuf -e "${CONTROL_PLANE_NODE_IPS[@]}"))
else
    echo "Error: No control plane node IPs available."
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "$(dirname $KUBECONFIG_PATH)"

for ip in "${SHUFFLED_IPS[@]}"; do
    echo "Trying control plane node at $ip..."
    # Get the join command from the control plane node
    JOIN_COMMAND=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY $USER@$ip 'kubeadm token create --print-join-command' 2>/dev/null)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Join command retrieved from control plane node at $ip: $JOIN_COMMAND"

        # Retrieve kubeconfig from the control plane node
        scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY $USER@$ip:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $KUBECONFIG_PATH
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Successfully retrieved kubeconfig from control plane node at $ip."
        else
            echo "Failed to retrieve kubeconfig from control plane node at $ip."
            exit 1
        fi

        # Attempt to join the worker node using the retrieved join command
        if eval "$JOIN_COMMAND"; then
            echo "Successfully joined the cluster using command from control plane node at $ip."
            break
        else
            echo "Failed to join the cluster using the retrieved join command from control plane node at $ip."
        fi
    else
        echo "Failed to retrieve join command from control plane node at $ip. Trying next..."
    fi
done

# Check if a join command was retrieved and successful
if [ -z "$JOIN_COMMAND" ]; then
    echo "Error: No join command could be retrieved from any control plane nodes."
    exit 1
fi

# Label the node as a worker after joining the cluster
NODE_NAME=$(hostname)
kubectl --kubeconfig="$KUBECONFIG_PATH" label node $NODE_NAME node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker --overwrite

kubectl --kubeconfig="$KUBECONFIG_PATH" label node $NODE_NAME role=worker --overwrite

echo "Kubernetes worker node setup complete!"

And the worker script also executes successfully and all the worker nodes are now connected to the control plane.
However, there seem to be issues with connectivity.
As it turns out pod-to-pod communication works via the private ips, but pod to external communication seems not to be working as evident in the logs from traefik which is the gateway controller I am using for the cluster:
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Traefik version 3.1.5 built on 2024-10-02T12:49:07Z version=3.1.5
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Stats collection is enabled.
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Many thanks for contributing to Traefik's improvement by allowing us to receive anonymous information from your configuration.
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Help us improve Traefik by leaving this feature on :)
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF More details on: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/contributing/data-collection/
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Label selector is: "" providerName=kubernetesgateway
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Creating in-cluster Provider client endpoint= providerName=kubernetesgateway
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Starting provider aggregator aggregator.ProviderAggregator
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Starting provider *traefik.Provider
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Starting provider *crd.Provider
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF label selector is: "" providerName=kubernetescrd
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Creating in-cluster Provider client providerName=kubernetescrd
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Starting provider *gateway.Provider
2024-10-08T12:27:27Z INF Starting provider *acme.ChallengeTLSALPN
2024-10-08T12:37:57Z WRN Error checking new version error="Get \"https://update.traefik.io/repos/traefik/traefik/releases\": dial tcp: lookup update.traefik.io: i/o timeout"

Also, one of the pods is also consistently crashing with the following error retrieved from the logs:
Defaulted container "csi-attacher" out of: csi-attacher, csi-resizer, csi-provisioner, liveness-probe, hcloud-csi-driver
I1008 13:31:30.822915       1 main.go:109] "Version" version="v4.7.0"
I1008 13:31:40.824824       1 connection.go:253] "Still connecting" address="unix:///run/csi/socket"
I1008 13:31:50.825437       1 connection.go:253] "Still connecting" address="unix:///run/csi/socket"
I1008 13:32:00.824918       1 connection.go:253] "Still connecting" address="unix:///run/csi/socket"
E1008 13:32:00.825053       1 main.go:149] "Failed to connect to the CSI driver" err="context deadline exceeded" csiAddress="/run/csi/socket

As a result I think there is a system connectivity problem in the cluster that needs to be fixed.
Please note that I have set up the infrastructure using terraform on hetzner cloud and here are the firewalls I applied to each node, I don't know if they could be part of the problem:
resource "hcloud_firewall" "k8s_firewall_control_plane" {
  name = "k8s-firewall-control-plane"

  # Ingress rules
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTPS Traffic for Control Planes"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "443"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Requests TCP - Kube API Server"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "6443"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTP Traffic for Control Plane"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "80"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming SSH Traffic for Control Plane"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "22"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Traffic for Kubelet"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "10250"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Liveness Probe Traffic for CSI Controller"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "9808"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow etcd client traffic"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    port        = "2379-2380"
    source_ips  = [
      hcloud_network.private_network.ip_range
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow kube-controller-manager traffic"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    port        = "10252"
    source_ips  = [
      hcloud_network.private_network.ip_range
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow kube-scheduler traffic"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    port        = "10251"
    source_ips  = [
      hcloud_network.private_network.ip_range
    ]
  }
   
   # Egress rules
   rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing HTTPS Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "443"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing HTTP Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "80"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing DNS Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "udp"
    port         = "53"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing TCP Traffic (any)"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "1-65535"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

}

resource "hcloud_firewall" "k8s_firewall_worker" {
  name = "k8s-firewall-worker"
  
  # Ingress rules
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming SSH Traffic for Workers"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "22"
    source_ips   = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTP Traffic for Workers"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "80"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTP Traffic for Workers"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "8000"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming HTTPS Traffic for Workers"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "443"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Traffic for Kubelet"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "10250"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Incoming Liveness Probe Traffic for CSI Controller"
    direction    = "in"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "9808"
    source_ips   = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Flannel VXLAN traffic"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "udp"
    port        = "8472"
    source_ips  = [
      hcloud_network.private_network.ip_range
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Flannel IP-in-IP traffic"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "udp"
    port        = "8285"
    source_ips  = [
      hcloud_network.private_network.ip_range
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow NodePort Services"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    port        = "30000-32767"
    source_ips  = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow NodePort Services UDP"
    direction   = "in"
    protocol    = "udp"
    port        = "30000-32767"
    source_ips  = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"
    ]
  }
  
  # Egress rules
  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing HTTPS Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "443"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing HTTP Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "80"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  
  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing DNS Traffic"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "udp"
    port         = "53"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  rule {
    description = "Allow Outgoing TCP Traffic (any)"
    direction    = "out"
    protocol     = "tcp"
    port         = "1-65535"
    destination_ips = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

}

And surprisingly all the CoreDNS pods are running perfectly fine with no issues.
I have tried all possible best to diagnose where the connectivity issue is coming from.
I will appreciate any ideas on what may be wrong with my setup.
Thanks in anticipation
